# Naming Convention Java for different class but same variable name

Tags: java, class, object, naming-conventions

Just needed some clarity on the below. Might be stupid but please throw some light on pros and cons.Assuming in IDE we search variables names while debugging and also during mapping or sending some data to others apps during that time.

```
Class State{
 private String stateName;
 private String stateCode;
}

Class City{
 private String cityName;
 private String cityCode;
}
```

is the above variable name fine or we should have names like

```
Class State{
 private String name;
 private String code;
}

Class City{
 private String name;
 private String code;
}
```

Assume that this would go as part of some CountryDTO to some api's.

I have tried to find this convention online but could not get anything more than the word **mnemonic**

Comment: The second example makes a lot more sense to me personally, because if i check the `name` field or call `getName()` on a `State` object it is kind of obvious that this refers to the name of a state. Adding "state" to every field seems simply redundand. But ultimately this is opinion based.

Comment: I think you wont face any problem in searching variables in either case. I would personally go with Second example. stateObject.name is self explanatory, no need to use "stateName"

Comment: It doesn't matter what you call private variables (they should be readable and not x y or z) but it very important to name the getter and setters properly. So people would know what are the setting or getting !

Comment: if this is a JPA Entity? and column names match the 1st example naming convention?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the naming convention depends on what the object is being used for. I would use the first example if I was querying a complex database that way the variable names most likely follows Column names inside the database. To me that helps any programmer read where in the database the object belongs etc.

If this is just a quick script the second example will work fine, I would just recommend that you at least document the variables!

Comment: if this is a JPA Entity? and column names match the 1st example naming convention?

Answer (score 0):

As the class name already defines the object type, it does not require each element within it to repeat itself.

```
   Class City {
     private String name;
     private String code;
   }
```

As you would name the instance of the object ex. `City city = new City();` you again have the class type being part of the name.

Just compare `city.name` to `city.cityName`, the first one is much simpler and cleaner.

Depending on the object complexity (amount of attributes each information consists of), it can happen that you need to define two attributes with the same name within the same object.

Simple example: `something.getCityName()` and `something.getCountryName()`, but this applies only if both city and country are not available as separate objects, as in that case it would be `something.getCity().getName()`.

Comment: if this is a JPA Entity? and column names match the 1st example naming convention?

Comment: Personally, I would still define them (both DTO and Entities) as already mentioned, and use the @Column annotation to adjust them to column names. Because if someone already made a naming convention "mistake" by including the table name as part of each column name, I would not continue the practice.